# Posterior Predictive Check on PyMC3 Deterministic Variable

Tags: python, theano, pymc3

**TL; DR**

What's the right way to do posterior predictive checks on `pm.Deterministic` variables that take stochastics (rendering the deterministic also stochastic) as input?

**Too Short; Didn't Understand**

Say we have a `pymc3` model like this:

```py
import pymc3 as pm

with pm.Model() as model:
    # Arbitrary, trainable distributions.
    dist1 = pm.Normal("dist1", 0, 1)
    dist2 = pm.Normal("dist2", dist1, 1)

    # Arbitrary, deterministic theano math.
    val1 = pm.Deterministic("val1", arb1(dist2))

    # Arbitrary custom likelihood.
    cdist = pm.DensityDistribution("cdist", logp(val1), observed=get_data())

    # Arbitrary, deterministic theano math.
    val2 = pm.Deterministic("val2", arb2(val1))
```

I may be misunderstanding, but my intention is for the posteriors of `dist1` and `dist2` to be sampled, and for those samples to fed into the deterministic variables. Is the posterior predictive check only possible on observed random variables?

It's straightforward to get posterior predictive samples from `dist2` and other random variables using `pymc3.sampling.sample_ppc`, but the majority of my model's value is derived from the state of `val1` and `val2`, given those samples.

The problem arises in that `pm.Deterministic(.)` seems to return a `th.TensorVariable`. So, when this is called:

```py
ppc = pm.sample_ppc(_trace, vars=[val1, val2])["val1", "val2"]
```

...and `pymc3` attempts this block of code in `pymc3.sampling`:

```py
    410        for var in vars:
--> 411            ppc[var.name].append(var.distribution.random(point=param,
    412                                                          size=size))
```

...it complains because a `th.TensorVariable` obviously doesn't have a `.distribution`.

So, what is the right way to carry the posterior samples of stochastics through deterministics? Do I need to explicitly create a `th.function` that takes stochastic posterior samples and calculates the deterministic values? That seems silly given the fact that `pymc3` already has the graph in place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, I was misunderstanding the purpose of `.sample_ppc`. You don't need it for unobserved variables because those have samples in the trace. Observed variables aren't sampled from, because their data is observed, thus you need `sample_ppc` to generate samples.

In short, I can gather samples of the `pm.Deterministic` variables from the trace.